# Speed of algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I was trying to find a fastest way to figure out the number of days in a month among the following three functions.

```
def f1():
    t=time.time()
    for month in range(1,13):
        for year in range(10001):
            leap_year=(year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0
            n=[29,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][month-2*leap_year*(month==2)]
    return time.time()-t1
def f2():
    t=time.time()
    for month in range(1,13):
        for year in range(10001):
            leap_year=(year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0
            n=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][month-1]+leap_year*(month==2)
    return time.time()-t
def f3():
    t=time.time()
    for month in range(1,13):
        for year in range(10001):
            leap_year=(year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0
            n={1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}[month]+leap_year*(month==2)
    return time.time()-t
print(sum(f1() for i in range(100)))
print(sum(f2() for i in range(100)))
print(sum(f3() for i in range(100)))
```

I was expecting the algorithm with dictionary would have the fastest speed. However, I got this:

```
3.7855005264282227
3.625513792037964
9.0009183883667
```

Obviously, I was wrong. Can someone explain why the dict algorithm has the least speed? It should take the least amount of time,O(1), and the list algorithms should take O(n), which is contradictory to the results I got.  I am very new to programming. Thanks!

Comment: I did not do much research on this, but notice your n is fairly small (12). I guess it turns out that computing a hash and finding an element in the hash table ends up taking longer than traversing through 12 elements of a list. Try to increase your n (more months) to see the speed up

Comment: Furthermore, you *are building a list and a dictionary* on each iteration.

Comment: Also, the only operations you are doing on the list and the dict is accessing an item, both list and dict have constant-time (i.e. O(1)) complexity for accessing an item. However, the actual speed of accessing from a list should be faster. But fundamentally, you are confused about what algorithmic complexity implies. It is about how algorithms *scale*, which you haven't really addressed with your examples.

Answer (score 3):

You're building a list / dictionary with every iteration.
If you build it only once (Since you're not changing it anyway), the f3() method is the fastest, The access time for both list and dict is O(1).

```
def f1():
    t=time.time()
    m=[29,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    for month in range(1,13):
        for year in range(10001):
            leap_year=(year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0
            n=m[month-2*leap_year*(month==2)]
    return time.time()-t
def f2():
    t=time.time()
    m=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    for month in range(1,13):
        for year in range(10001):
            leap_year=(year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0
            n=m[month-1]+leap_year*(month==2)
    return time.time()-t



def f3():
    t=time.time()
    m={1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}
    for month in range(1,13):
        for year in range(10001):
            leap_year=(year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0
            n=m[month]+leap_year*(month==2)
    return time.time()-t


print(sum(f1() for i in range(100)))
print(sum(f2() for i in range(100)))
print(sum(f3() for i in range(100)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it! Is there a better way to calculate the number of days in a month?